# SQL Server Select Query and Join to Multiple Databases in One Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario like this and I want to know if there is a way to solve this only using SQL queries:

I have n databases, with name *tenant_1*, *tenant_2*, *tenant_3*, ... , *tenant_n* and a database named *main*.
In *main* database, there's a table named *tenants* with following structure

| tenant_name | tenant_db |
| --- | --- |
| Tenant 1 | tenant_1 |
| Tenant 2 | tenant_2 |
| Tenant n | tenant_n |

In each tenant database, there's a table named *settings* with following structure

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| DATE | 2022-12-15 |
| ... | ... |

Can I join the the *tenants* table to each *settings* table from each database? So the end result will be

| tenant_name | tenant_db | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tenant 1 | tenant_1 | 2022-12-15 |
| Tenant 2 | tenant_2 | 2022-12-15 |
| Tenant n | tenant_n | 2022-12-15 |

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The problem here is your design; you should have one table with the tenant details in, not *n* databases with *n* tables. You *cannot* `JOIN` dynamically to different tables, let alone different tables in different databases. Not to mention that as the tables are in different databases referential integrity will be impossible.

Comment: Currently we need this thing for some BI things, and I just wondering if we can to this kind of query without using ETL. But anyway, thank you for your answer